# How can I get the current state of a WPF window into an image?

Tags: .net, wpf

I would like to be able to basically have a button which allows me to save a picture of the current state of a WPF window.

Ideall, I would like to be able to send this picture to the clipboard.

At the moment, the user uses the "Print Screen" keyboard touch, but he then has to go through pain to select only the window in question.

Is there a programmatic way to get all the content of a WPF window in the clipboard or as an image?

Comment: `Alt + PrtSc` only prints the active window by the way...

Comment: @H.B.: ah that's cool. I'll still let the question open as I would like to know how to possibly store it automatically somewhere for example. But you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `VisualBrush` and bind it to your root element.

[Here](http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/09/wpf-copy-uielement-as-image-to-clipboard/) is a link that does exactly what you want.